# Serialize generic for web socket

Tags: c#, serialization, web, websocket

I'm using Super Web Socket for a while, it is great, all work, I can send commands and no issues.Now I'm tring to send bulk of commands inside one command, I saw that if I send lots of small commands the websocketStart work verrrrry slow, so I come out with new command to collect few commands and send them in one shot.I'm dealing with serialize issue, whould be glad if you help me.My command will send the BulkCMD_Structure to client.I get only CommandID in the array :(

```
 #region BulkCommand
[Serializable]
public class BulkCMD_Structure
{
    public Int64 UserID { get; set; }
    public int DataArrayLength { get; set; }
    public List<BulkCMD_Data> DataArray;
}

[Serializable]
public class BulkCMD_Data
{
    public eWebSocketCMD CommandID { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class BulkWindowCMD_Data : BulkCMD_Data
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class BulkMouseStatusCMD_Data : BulkCMD_Data
{
    public int mousePositionX { get; set; }
    public int mousePositionY { get; set; }
}
#endregion
```

I also tried the following, but get serialization ERROR:

```
#region BulkCommand
[Serializable]
public class BulkCMD_Structure
{
    public Int64 UserID { get; set; }
    public int DataArrayLength { get; set; }
    public iBulkCMD_Data [] DataArray;
}
[Serializable]
public class iBulkCMD_Data
{
    eWebSocketCMD CommandID { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class BulkWindowCMD_Data : iBulkCMD_Data
{
    public eWebSocketCMD CommandID { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class BulkMouseStatusCMD_Data : iBulkCMD_Data
{
    public eWebSocketCMD CommandID { get; set; }
    public int mousePositionX { get; set; }
    public int mousePositionY { get; set; }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: define "serialization ERROR". What happens? What is the full exception text (including any `.InnerException`s), if there is an exception? Also: what serializer are you using? The `[Serializable]` suggests `BinaryFormatter`, but that would be pretty unusual for a web-socket, unless this is server-to-server. And even then I'd say it is not the best choice.

Comment: Also: what is `eWebSocketCMD` ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply changed the:

iBulkCMD_Data [] DataArray or

List DataArray

to object [] DataArray